# How to insert current user id(in session) name into table column of createdby & updatedby

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have table like this...but My design page contain only one text area,thats for question answer column,my table like this`

```
public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    [StringLength(1500, MinimumLength = 50, ErrorMessage = "Invalid")]
    public string Question_Answer { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswer { get; set; }
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public bool IsMarkedAsAnswer { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public int UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}'
```

And My Controller Like This,Then how to insret created by updated by column with the help of current userid from session??

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserAccountModel model)
    {
        StackProvider provider = new StackProvider();
        model.UserAccount = provider.GetUseraccountByEmailPassword(model.UserAccount.Email, model.UserAccount.Password);

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserAccount.Exception))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserAccount.Email", model.UserAccount.Exception);
            return View(model);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["UserId"] = model.UserAccount.UserId; 
             Session["UserName"] = model.UserAccount.UserName;
            Session["Email"] = model.UserAccount.Email;
            return RedirectToAction("Homepage", "QuestionAnswer");
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using ?

Comment: Whenever you'll call a method to save the data into the table "QuestionAnswer" pass the "Session["UserName"] to that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Action that save the `QuestionAnswer` model, e.g.:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(QuestionAnswer model)
{
    ...
    var userId = (int)Session["UserID"];
    model.CreatedBy = userId;
    model.UpdatedBy = userId;
    ...
}
```